# Connecting Arduino Standalone Chip and XBee

Tags: arduino, xbee

I took out my arduino chip from my board and followed the instructions to put it on a breadboard here: http://itp.nyu.edu/physcomp/uploads/arduinobb_09.jpg
Everything works fine but when I plug in an XBee, the code doesnt work the way it should.

The code I was using was two simple statements in the `setup()` function

1. Starting the Serial port:

   `Serial.begin(9600);`
2. Printing a line:

   `Serial.println("Hello World");`

The problem is that it repeatedly sends this message over the XBee and I can see from the receiver XBee that it rapidly sends `"Hello World"` over and over. Also, if  I check the voltage supplied by the voltage regulator, it is only 3.7 volts rather than 5 volts.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Re voltage: what's the voltage provided to the regulator? If you only provide 5V on input, you will not get 5V on output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likely explanation as to why `setup()` is being executed continually is that the chip is being repeatedly reset. This is likely to be related to the low voltage you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Yea sorry about this guys. I finally figured out the problem. The batteries I was using were not delivering enough current and power to supply both the arduino and xbee. The thing is, since the batteries were cheap, they ran out really quick of charge and I thought that it was a problem. Better batteries were the solution however.